# How to addClass and remove Class when clicking a link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make some elements active when I click on a link. I'm at this code right now which let's me add and remove active class when I click on element with class 'test'. What I need is to click a link and have the same behaviour to the div elements.

I have:

```js
$('.test').on('click',function(){
  $('.test.active').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active{
  color: #F00;
}
```

```html
<div class='test active'>test</div>
<div class='test'>test</div>

<a class='link' href=''>Click me</a>
```

This code adds and removes the active class when I click the divs. How to do the same thing by clicking the link?

Comment: What is exactly expected behaviour? On first click? On second click? On third click? Etc... Your question is unclear

Comment: Why the downvote? I think this is a pretty legitimate question. And I didn't found the answer on SO.

Comment: Your code works fine, you just haven't included the jQuery library in the snippet.

Comment: @A.Wolff, expected behaviour is when I click the link to do the same thing as when I click the div with the class 'test'

Comment: @Anonymous doing the same thing should suffice

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, I think you misundertood my question. Now I add and remove the class active when I click the element with class 'test'. I need to do the same thing, but when I click the link.

Comment: That makes no sense. How can you do 'the same thing' (which is highlight the current `.test` element) when you won't be clicking on the `.test` element...? When clicking the `a`, which of the `.test` elements should have the `active` class added to it?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, should remove it from the previous with active and add it to the next one.

Comment: @Anonymous check my answer. It is what you want.

Comment: @Anonymous And what should happen when the last is reach? Should then the first be `.active` or what? Are you looking for a cycle row, an alternate cycle or a stopping at last? You can see your question is really missing info regarding your expected behaviour. QSaying 'i want to do the same but clicking on unrelevant element' brings a lot of confusion. That's why the downvotes i guess

Comment: Have updated my post that will work for multiple elements. Check it out.

Comment: @A.Wolff, no it's not a cycle, when reaches last I'm doing something else. I provided only a simple example, my real code looks a lot more different. But the logic is the same.

Comment: @Anonymous And are these `.test` elements siblings in your real use case? Meaning directly following each other, without any wrapper? Anyway, i think with all answers provided here, you should be able to finally pick up one that fits your expected result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like following. It will add and remove active class on link click.

```js
$('.link').on('click', function(){
  $('.active').removeClass('active').siblings('.test').addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active{
  color: #F00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='test active'>test</div>
<div class='test'>test</div>

<a class='link' href='#'>Click me</a>
```

**Edit:**

This will work for infinite div.

JQuery:

```
$('.link').on('click', function(){
   if($('.active').next().hasClass('test'))
  {
     $('.active').removeClass('active').next('.test').addClass('active');
  }
 else
 {
   $('.active').removeClass('active');
   $('.test:first').addClass('active');
 }
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h5f5h6yn/1/)

Comment: @Anonymous Updated My answer.

Comment: Can you show me the same behaviour in a pure javascript way please. I need to have some dynamic ids and classes. Thanks.

Comment: @Anonymous I think this is not possible in JAVAScript or too difficult to make it javascript. So, as per my opinion better to use JQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Add `href="javascript:;"` if to avoid redirection.

In jQuery below snippet will work:

```
$('.link').on('click', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
})
```

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m8bfLd42/)**

**Update**

To highlight multiple `divs`

```
$('.link').on('click', function(){

    if($('.test.active').next().hasClass('test'))
    {
        $('.test.active').removeClass('active').next('.test').addClass('active');
    }
    else
    {
        $('.test.active').removeClass('active');
        $('.test:first').addClass('active');
    }
})
```

**[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m8bfLd42/2/)**

Comment: No, I don't want to add the active class on the link. I want to add it on the next div with class test

Answer (score 1):

When you click a link, the behavior and the method will be the same as if you click a button, a div, or any other element of the page.

The difference is that an `<a>` element will redirect you to another page (inclusive if it's "the same" where you come from) and the changes won't be noticeable.

You will need to use `$("element").addClass("class");`

Comment: I know how to use preventDefault(); That's not the problem

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be:

```
$('.link').on('click', function () {
    var $nextActive = $('.test.active').next('.test').length ? $('.test.active').next('.test') : $('.test').first();
    $('.test.active').add($nextActive).toggleClass('active');
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your post and comments you'd like to use link as class changer for divs. Here you go. Edited!

```
$('.link').on('click', function(){
    $('.test.active').toggleClass('active').next().addClass("active");
});
```

Working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/02kL4fvm/3/)

Comment: I think you're the only one who understood me. I don't understand the downvotes to my question when the other answers are wrong and have upvotes. :) Thanks man.

Comment: That's great! =) Hope it will work for you. If so - you're welcome to "approve" the answer. Or comment here on any questions.

Comment: There is no need for each loop

Comment: @Anonymous You said in comment: `Should remove it from the previous with active and add it to the next one` So this solution won't work if you have more than two `.test` elements or none `.test.active` by default

Comment: @A. Wolff, So what is the solution then? Cause I have more than two .test elements indeed

Comment: I've updated the answer - see it now. Thank you, @A.Wolff

Comment: @Anonymous I have posted an answer BUT still unclear what you are expecting. See my comment under your question

Answer (score 0):

Just remove .active class.
below code is working.

```
$('.test').click(function(){
$('.test').removeClass('active');
$(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

replace js function

```
$('.test').on('click',function(){
      $('.test').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
 });
```

Demo Link https://jsfiddle.net/ffjcfb2b/